# How to know max using memory in Oracle XE11g release 2?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe

What the max using memory in Oracle XE11g release 2 , i had read in oracle documentation that allowed max memory for database is 1GB RAM ,
IF it per Database or user and if it per database , how i can modify it per user ??

Answer (score 1):

1GB is right, and it's for the database (not per user).

You may want to post your question on StackExchange - dba.stackexchange.com; people there may be able to help more.

As far as I know, you can't limit memory usage per user - you can limit memory usage PER SESSION (only in a shared server architecture, which I don't know if the express Edition uses). This is in a user's PROFILE: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm#i2066025 - see the "size clause" for PRIVATE SGA.